# JQuery dynamic form creation removes existing input field

Tags: jquery, forms, dom

I have an input search field. Now during a dynamic form creation in jquery, this search field is getting removed from its parent div and being added to the new form. Moreover, a dynamic input of type hidden which is supposed to be created, is not being created. Please find below my code. Please help to resolve this problem. Thanks in advance.

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div class="searchArea">
        <input id="searchField" name="searchNotice" type="text">
        <button id="searchButton" class="iconButton" data-tooltip-text="Search"><i class="fy fy-magnify"></i></button>
    </div>
    <div class="downloadArea">
        <button id="downloadIDPDF" ntag="6">Download ID Card</button>
    </div>
</body>
```

**JQuery**

```
$('#downloadIDPDF').click(function()
{
    $empID  = $(this).attr('ntag');
    var url = './lib/emp_id_pdf.lib.php';       

    $("<form>")
    .attr("action", url)
    .attr("method", "post")
    .append($("input").attr("type", "hidden").attr("name", "emp_id").attr("value", $empID))
    .appendTo("body")
    .submit()
    .get(0)
    .reset()
    .remove();
});
```

**Final HTML**

```
<body>
    <div class="searchArea">            
        <button id="searchButton" class="iconButton" data-tooltip-text="Search"><i class="fy fy-magnify"></i></button>
    </div>
    <div class="downloadArea">
        <button id="downloadIDPDF" ntag="6">Download ID Card</button>
    </div>
    <form action="./lib/emp_id_pdf.lib.php" method="post">
        <input id="searchField" name="searchNotice" type="hidden" value="2">
    </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

this is happening dude to   append($(input).attr("type", "hidden").attr("name", "emp_id").attr("value", $empID)) - as it is working as a selector and selecting all the inputs on the dom and appending it to the form, you can do something like this.

```
$('#downloadIDPDF').click(function()
{
    $empID  = $(this).attr('ntag');
    var url = './lib/emp_id_pdf.lib.php';       
    var input = '<input>'
    $("<form>")
    .attr("action", url)
    .attr("method", "post")
    .append($(input).attr("type", "hidden").attr("name", "emp_id").attr("value", $empID))
    .appendTo("body")
  .submit()
    .get(0)
    .reset()
    .remove();
});
```

hope this helps :)